# finding all possible arrangements of list elements until the combination reaches a provided length

Tags: python, python-3.x, combinations, permutation

Suppose a list `L=[a,b]` , I want to find all possible combinations of this list and stop when the combination reach a specific length. For example: I want to stop it after combination reaches length `2`. the result should be `['aa', 'ab', 'ba', 'bb']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [itertools.product(list, repeat=2)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) - return cartesian product of input iterables.

**Ex.**

```
import itertools
a = ['a','b']
combination = [''.join(x) for x in itertools.product(a,repeat=2)]
print(combination)
```

**O/P:**

```
['aa', 'ab', 'ba', 'bb']
```